# Update View with UNION changes TINYINT to BIGINT

Tags: mysql, casting, type-conversion, boolean, tinyint

I'm adding information to a view via `UNION`. I currently have booleans in the table represented by `TINYINT`. I need to maintain these columns as `TINYINT`. The following information in the `UNION` alters the datatype to `BIGINT`:

```
<PREVIOUS SELECT (Type of isRequired = TINYINT)>
    SELECT isRequired
    FROM tableA
    UNION
<NEW SELECT (After this, isRequired = BIGINT)>
    SELECT
    1 AS isRequired
    FROM tableB
```

Apparently, MYSQL `CAST()` will not convert to `TINYINT`. How can I preserve the `TINYINT` in the original view?

Comment: What is the `<PREVIOUS` and `<NEW` stuff? That's not valid SQL syntax.

Comment: Why do you need to maintain the columns as `TINYINT`? As long as the values are  always in the range of `TINYINT` you shouldn't notice a difference.

Comment: MySQL is very forgiving about data types. It only complains if a value is too big to fit into a place where it's being stored, not if the data types don't match.

Comment: [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/gJorWjQkD6nPoWXM5d9Rmo/0) is one way :-)

Comment: @PaulSpiegel HACKS i like it :-)  One step futher if you use `CREATE temporary TABLE test LIKE tmp2;`  after it becomes a native `TINYINT` datetype  -> https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/gJorWjQkD6nPoWXM5d9Rmo/1

Comment: @RaymondNijland I don't get it.. It's just a ["copy" of tmp2](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/om3XTRStpWp7EbkMikuPoU/0)

Comment: indeed @PaulSpiegel mine point is then you drop tmp2 and you can use test without the need of a select `(select isRequired FROM tableA where isRequired = 1 limit 1)` to do a "implict type cast" in there to "optimize" ..

Comment: Well - I doubt that this is of any value :-) - It's still not clear what exactly is the problem with BIGINT.

Comment: Well @PaulSpiegel imagine is you have millions / billions of bigint records which all needs to be converted... i agree this can be "micro" optimisation with a low number of records. .

Comment: If I'd want a table with TYNYINT I'd just CREATE one :-)

Comment: @PaulSpiegel  *"It's still not clear what exactly is the problem with BIGINT. "* Data mapper (types) issues maybe on the client side? No ideaaa what else..

Comment: @RaymondNijland - Correct. The Data mapping on the client side requires that I do not alter the data type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know why you "need to maintain these columns as `TINYINT`". However - One workaround would be to define a custom function which returns a `TINYINT` value.

```
create function cast2tinyint(v bigint)
  returns tinyint
  deterministic no sql
  return v;
```

Then your query would be

```
SELECT isRequired
FROM tableA
UNION
SELECT
cast2tinyint(1) AS isRequired
FROM tableA
```

You can test it storing the result into a (temporary) table.

Original query:

```
create temporary table tmp1
    SELECT isRequired
    FROM tableA
    UNION
    SELECT
    1 AS isRequired
    FROM tableA
;

show create table tmp1;
```

Result:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE `tmp1` (
  `isRequired` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL
)
```

Using custom function:

```
create temporary table tmp2
    SELECT isRequired
    FROM tableA
    UNION
    SELECT
    cast2tinyint(1) AS isRequired
    FROM tableA
;

show create table tmp2;
```

Result:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE `tmp2` (
  `isRequired` tinyint(4) DEFAULT NULL
)
```

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/hFfUffPT9KaqfzVMK8wi46/0)